# Sending Email without AUTHENTICATION using PHPmailer and Gmail SMTP

Tags: smtp, gmail, phpmailer

I'm using PHPmailer and GMail as my SMTP server for my email app. My question is, is it possible to send an email without authentication(without having to define username and password in the phpmailer config)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

No, gmail will not let you send without authentication. And yes, this means you need to have authentication info available in your script. You can obfuscate things by doing something like base-64 encoding the values so they are not visible as plain text.